# Exclude records with column value starting with '836'

Tags: sql, sql-server, notin

So my latest issue is I need to be able to exclude records with claim numbers that start with '836'. This seems pretty straight forward, but nothing I've tried seems to be working, as I'm still getting back claim numbers starting with '836'. I've tried using NOT LIKE and NOT IN.

Could I please be advised what I'm doing wrong? I'm including the query and my comments. Thanks in advance for your input.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime = '1/1/2017'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##ProducerCommBridge') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ##ProducerCommBridge;

SELECT DISTINCT [ProducerCommBridgeKey]
      ,[PolicyAgreementNumber]
      ,[CommissionStartDate]
      ,[CommissionEndDate]
  INTO ##ProducerCommBridge
FROM [dbo].[DimProducerCommBridge]
;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##FctLossData') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ##FctLossData;

CREATE TABLE ##FctLossData (
    [QIPS_LPRG_SID] numeric(10,0) null,
    [PACClaimID] nvarchar(50) NULL,
    [EquipmentID] int null,
    [ClaimID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimNumber] [varchar](34) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LossDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProCloseDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProducerCommBridgeKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ClaimStatus] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [ContractNumber] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [PolicyID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ProductID] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [CatastropheID] [int] NULL,
    [InsuranceClassCode] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [EquipmentName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [EquipmentClassName] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [EquipmentDescription] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [RegionCode] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [CountryCode] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [ClaimLossType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CauseOfLoss] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [EnrollmentID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CoverageID] [int] NULL,
    [CoverageEffectiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CustomerAccountNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PaidLossAmount] [money] NULL,
    [CaseReserveAmount] [money] NULL,
    [RecoveryReserveAmount] [money] NULL,
    [SalvageRecoveryAmount] [money] NULL,
    [SubroRecoveryAmount] [money] NULL,
    [TotalRecoveryAmount] [money] NULL,
    [AllocatedLAEAmount] [money] NULL
)
;

INSERT INTO ##FctLossData

--DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime = '1/1/2017'

SELECT
  qle.LPRG_SID
  ,lc.PACClaimID
  ,ems.EquipmentID
  ,c.ClaimID
  ,(c.ClaimPrefix + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, c.ClaimNumber)) AS ClaimNumber
  ,CONVERT(date, CreateDate) AS CreateDate
  ,CONVERT(date, c.LossDate) AS LossDate
  ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, EffectiveDate) < 17 then CONVERT(date, EffectiveDate) ELSE CONVERT(date, dateadd(dd, 1, EffectiveDate)) END as ProCloseDate
  ,-1 AS ProducerCommBridgeKey
  ,cs.ClaimStatus
  ,UPPER(LEFT(c.ContractNumber, 10)) AS ContractNumber
  ,CASE WHEN c.ContractNumber IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END AS PolicyID
  ,sCustomerID AS CustomerID
  ,CASE WHEN pro.sProductID = '9095' THEN '1095' ELSE pro.sProductID END AS ProductID
  ,c.CatastropheID
  ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END AS InsuranceClassCode
  ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END AS EquipmentName
  ,CASE WHEN EquipmentClassName IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentClassName)))) END AS EquipmentClassName
  ,CASE WHEN EquipmentDescription IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentDescription)))) END AS EquipmentDescription
  ,RegionCode
  ,CountryCode
  ,CASE WHEN ClaimLossType IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ClaimLossType END AS ClaimLossType
  ,CASE WHEN CauseOfLoss IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE CauseOfLoss END AS CauseOfLoss
  ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_SID) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lc.EnrollmentID) ELSE NULL END AS EnrollmentID
  ,NULL AS CoverageID
  ,NULL AS CoverageEffectiveDate
  ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_LEASE_CODE) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lefs.ContractNumber) ELSE NULL END AS CustomerAccountNumber
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 1 THEN Amount END) AS PaidLossAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 1 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 1 THEN Amount END) AS CaseReserveAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 1 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID IN (1, 7, 8) THEN Amount END) AS RecoveryReserveAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID = 8 THEN Amount END) AS SalvageRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID = 7 THEN Amount END) AS SubroRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID IN (1, 7, 8) THEN Amount END) AS TotalRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 6 THEN Amount END) AS AllocatedLAEAmount     
  FROM dbo.ExtPACTransaction t
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPACClaim c ON t.ClaimID = c.ClaimID
                              --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT LIKE '836%'
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDEPolicy pol ON (CASE WHEN [ContractNumber] IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END) = pol.sPolicyID
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDECustomer cus ON pol.iCustomerKey = cus.iCustomerKey
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDEProduct pro ON pol.iProductKey = pro.iProductKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtPACClaimStatus cs ON c.ClaimID = cs.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtJWProductSegment jw ON pro.sProductID = jw.sProductID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtEMSEquipment ems ON c.EMIEquipmentID = CONVERT(varchar, ems.EquipmentNumber)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtQIPSClaims qc ON qc.CLAM_PAC_CLAIMID = c.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtQIPSLeaseEnrollment qle ON qle.LPRG_SID = qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtLP2Claim lc ON lc.PACClaimID = c.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtLP2EnrollmentForSearch lefs ON lefs.EnrollmentID = lc.EnrollmentID
  WHERE c.LossDate >= @StartDate
  --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT LIKE '836%' -- To remove FIS claims
  --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT IN (SELECT c2.ClaimNumber FROM ExtPACClaim c2 WHERE ClaimNumber LIKE '836%')
  AND c.isVoided = 0
  AND (pro.sProductID = '9095' OR jw.sProductID IS NOT NULL)
  GROUP BY qle.LPRG_SID
    ,lc.PACClaimID
    ,ems.EquipmentID
    ,c.ClaimID
    ,(c.ClaimPrefix + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, c.ClaimNumber)) 
    ,CONVERT(date, CreateDate) 
    ,CONVERT(date, c.LossDate) 
    ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, t.EffectiveDate) < 17 then CONVERT(date, t.EffectiveDate) ELSE CONVERT(date, dateadd(dd, 1, t.EffectiveDate)) END
    ,cs.ClaimStatus
    , UPPER(LEFT(c.ContractNumber, 10))
    ,CASE WHEN c.ContractNumber IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END 
    ,sCustomerID 
    ,CASE WHEN pro.sProductID = '9095' THEN '1095' ELSE pro.sProductID END 
    ,c.CatastropheID
    ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END
    ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END
    ,CASE WHEN EquipmentClassName IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentClassName)))) END
    ,CASE WHEN EquipmentDescription IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentDescription)))) END
    ,RegionCode
    ,CountryCode
    ,CASE WHEN ClaimLossType IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ClaimLossType END
    ,CASE WHEN CauseOfLoss IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE CauseOfLoss END 
    ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_SID) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lc.EnrollmentID) ELSE NULL END
    ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_LEASE_CODE) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lefs.ContractNumber) ELSE NULL END

  --ORDER BY ClaimNumber DESC
;

--To view records
SELECT *
FROM ##FctLossData
WHERE ClaimNumber LIKE '836%'
```

Comment: try add  a (simple) data sample  you expected  result and you actual result  ..

Comment: That doesn't look like standard SQL. What DBMS is this?

Comment: I see you have "CONVERT(varchar, c.ClaimNumber))" in the query, so the claim number is not varchar. See if there is something going on with implicit conversion to character when the LIKE is being applied. (Looks like SQL Server to me.)

Comment: Your query is looking perfect. can you share some data to check.

Answer (score 0):

I added a column `ClaimNumberWithoutPrefix` and filter based on this. Your original ClaimNumber has something like this at the beginning `c.ClaimPrefix + '-'`. Be aware that if `c.ClaimPrefix` `is null` then the whole expressions `is null`. To avoid this you can use `concat(c.ClaimPrefix + '-', c.ClaimNumber)`

```
SELECT
  qle.LPRG_SID
  ,lc.PACClaimID
  ,ems.EquipmentID
  ,c.ClaimID
  ,(c.ClaimPrefix + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, c.ClaimNumber)) AS ClaimNumber
  ,ClaimNumber as ClaimNumberWithoutPrefix
  ,CONVERT(date, CreateDate) AS CreateDate
  ,CONVERT(date, c.LossDate) AS LossDate
  ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, EffectiveDate) < 17 then CONVERT(date, EffectiveDate) ELSE CONVERT(date, dateadd(dd, 1, EffectiveDate)) END as ProCloseDate
  ,-1 AS ProducerCommBridgeKey
  ,cs.ClaimStatus
  ,UPPER(LEFT(c.ContractNumber, 10)) AS ContractNumber
  ,CASE WHEN c.ContractNumber IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END AS PolicyID
  ,sCustomerID AS CustomerID
  ,CASE WHEN pro.sProductID = '9095' THEN '1095' ELSE pro.sProductID END AS ProductID
  ,c.CatastropheID
  ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END AS InsuranceClassCode
  ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END AS EquipmentName
  ,CASE WHEN EquipmentClassName IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentClassName)))) END AS EquipmentClassName
  ,CASE WHEN EquipmentDescription IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentDescription)))) END AS EquipmentDescription
  ,RegionCode
  ,CountryCode
  ,CASE WHEN ClaimLossType IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ClaimLossType END AS ClaimLossType
  ,CASE WHEN CauseOfLoss IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE CauseOfLoss END AS CauseOfLoss
  ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_SID) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lc.EnrollmentID) ELSE NULL END AS EnrollmentID
  ,NULL AS CoverageID
  ,NULL AS CoverageEffectiveDate
  ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_LEASE_CODE) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lefs.ContractNumber) ELSE NULL END AS CustomerAccountNumber
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 1 THEN Amount END) AS PaidLossAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 1 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 1 THEN Amount END) AS CaseReserveAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 1 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID IN (1, 7, 8) THEN Amount END) AS RecoveryReserveAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID = 8 THEN Amount END) AS SalvageRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID = 7 THEN Amount END) AS SubroRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 1 AND TranTypeID IN (1, 7, 8) THEN Amount END) AS TotalRecoveryAmount
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN Reserve = 0 AND Recovery = 0 AND TranTypeID = 6 THEN Amount END) AS AllocatedLAEAmount     
  FROM dbo.ExtPACTransaction t
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPACClaim c ON t.ClaimID = c.ClaimID
                              --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT LIKE '836%'
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDEPolicy pol ON (CASE WHEN [ContractNumber] IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END) = pol.sPolicyID
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDECustomer cus ON pol.iCustomerKey = cus.iCustomerKey
  INNER JOIN dbo.ExtPRSDEProduct pro ON pol.iProductKey = pro.iProductKey
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtPACClaimStatus cs ON c.ClaimID = cs.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtJWProductSegment jw ON pro.sProductID = jw.sProductID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtEMSEquipment ems ON c.EMIEquipmentID = CONVERT(varchar, ems.EquipmentNumber)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtQIPSClaims qc ON qc.CLAM_PAC_CLAIMID = c.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtQIPSLeaseEnrollment qle ON qle.LPRG_SID = qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtLP2Claim lc ON lc.PACClaimID = c.ClaimID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ExtLP2EnrollmentForSearch lefs ON lefs.EnrollmentID = lc.EnrollmentID
  WHERE c.LossDate >= @StartDate
  --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT LIKE '836%' -- To remove FIS claims
  --AND c.ClaimNumber NOT IN (SELECT c2.ClaimNumber FROM ExtPACClaim c2 WHERE ClaimNumber LIKE '836%')
  AND c.isVoided = 0
  AND (pro.sProductID = '9095' OR jw.sProductID IS NOT NULL)
  GROUP BY qle.LPRG_SID
    ,lc.PACClaimID
    ,ems.EquipmentID
    ,c.ClaimID
    ,(c.ClaimPrefix + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, c.ClaimNumber)) 
    ,ClaimNumber
    ,CONVERT(date, CreateDate) 
    ,CONVERT(date, c.LossDate) 
    ,CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, t.EffectiveDate) < 17 then CONVERT(date, t.EffectiveDate) ELSE CONVERT(date, dateadd(dd, 1, t.EffectiveDate)) END
    ,cs.ClaimStatus
    , UPPER(LEFT(c.ContractNumber, 10))
    ,CASE WHEN c.ContractNumber IS NOT NULL THEN LEFT(c.PolicyNumber, 7) ELSE c.PolicyNumber END 
    ,sCustomerID 
    ,CASE WHEN pro.sProductID = '9095' THEN '1095' ELSE pro.sProductID END 
    ,c.CatastropheID
    ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(InsuranceClassCode)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END
    ,CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName))) = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE COALESCE(UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentName)))), 'UNKNOWN')  END
    ,CASE WHEN EquipmentClassName IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentClassName)))) END
    ,CASE WHEN EquipmentDescription IS NULL THEN 'UNKNOWN' ELSE UPPER(LTRIM(RTRIM(dbo.fn_clean_string(EquipmentDescription)))) END
    ,RegionCode
    ,CountryCode
    ,CASE WHEN ClaimLossType IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE ClaimLossType END
    ,CASE WHEN CauseOfLoss IS NULL THEN 'Unknown' ELSE CauseOfLoss END 
    ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_SID) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lc.EnrollmentID) ELSE NULL END
    ,CASE WHEN qc.CLAM_LPRG_SID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), qle.LEAS_LEASE_CODE) WHEN lc.EnrollmentID IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(50), lefs.ContractNumber) ELSE NULL END

  --ORDER BY ClaimNumber DESC
;

--To view records
SELECT *
FROM ##FctLossData
WHERE ClaimNumberWithoutPrefix LIKE '836%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[^] NotIn` pattern matching in LIKE clause to filter out values, starting with 836. I have given sample code below for your reference. Read more about [LIKE clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/like.php)

```
CREATE TABLE #test(ClaimNumber VARCHAR(34))

INSERT INTO #test values('836789'),('567890'),('423897')

SELECT * FROM #test
WHERE claimNumber LIKE '[^8][^3][^6]%'
```

btw, I see that you are using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, ClaimNumber)`. Always specify length for `VARCHAR`. If you do not specify length, it will be applying different default length in different places. In the case of CONVERT, it will be applying `VARCHAR(30)`. In the table creation column definition, it will be applying `VARCHAR(1)`. I would suggest you to read about this [TSQL bad practice](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)